# GeometryConstructors.Polygon: LinearRing requires at least 3 points

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run the following code to extract the change map using the Land Trendr algorithm in Google Earth Engine. Everything seems to be running fine when I use a point as my area of interest, but once I try to use a polygon as my aoi file it throws me an error. I am attaching my code here :

```
//##########################################################################################
// START INPUTS
//##########################################################################################

// define collection parameters

var startYear = 1985;
var endYear = 2017;
var startDay = '06-20';
var endDay = '09-20';

//var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(-122.8848, 43.7929);

var coords = ([70.9361058400289,28.387332974875402],
              [83.5044652150289,28.387332974875402],
              [83.5044652150289,37.305336609850876],
              [70.9361058400289,37.305336609850876],
              [70.9361058400289,28.387332974875402]);

var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords);

var index = 'NBR';
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'snow', 'water'];

// define landtrendr parameters

var runParams = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};

// define change parameters

var changeParams = {
  delta:  'loss',
  sort:   'greatest',
  year:   {checked:false, start:2000, end:2010},
  mag:    {checked:true,  value:200,  operator: '\>', dsnr:false},
  dur:    {checked:true,  value:4,    operator: '\<'},
  preval: {checked:true,  value:300,  operator: '\>'},
  mmu:    {checked:true,  value:11},
};

//##########################################################################################
// END INPUTS
//##########################################################################################

// load the LandTrendr.js module

var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js'); 

// add index to changeParams object

changeParams.index = index;

// run landtrendr

var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, index, [], runParams,     maskThese);

// get the change map layers

var changeImg = ltgee.getChangeMap(lt, changeParams);

// set visualization dictionaries
var palette = ['#9400D3', '#4B0082', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF7F00', '#FF0000'];
var yodVizParms = {
min: startYear,
max: endYear,
palette: palette
};

var magVizParms = {
min: 200,
max: 800,
palette: palette
};

// display the change attribute map - note that there are other layers - print changeImg to console to see

Map.centerObject(aoi, 11);
Map.addLayer(changeImg.select(['mag']), magVizParms, 'Magnitude of Change');
Map.addLayer(changeImg.select(['yod']), yodVizParms, 'Year of Detection');

// export change data to google drive

var region = aoi.buffer(1000).bounds();
var exportImg = changeImg.clip(region).unmask(0).short();
Export.image.toDrive(
{image: exportImg,description: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map', 
folder: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map', 
fileNamePrefix: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map',
region: region, 
scale: 30,
crs: 'EPSG:5070',
maxPixels: 1e13});
```

It is throwing an error: Line 75: GeometryConstructors.Polygon: LinearRing requires at least 3 points. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords, proj, geodesic, maxError, evenOdd) function requires coords as list. The coords variable should be defined as list as follows:

```
var coords = ([[
[70.9361058400289,28.387332974875402],
[83.5044652150289,28.387332974875402],
[83.5044652150289,37.305336609850876],
[70.9361058400289,37.305336609850876],
[70.9361058400289,28.387332974875402]
]]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).